# Best practice for getting JSON Feed of Wordpress posts tagged under a specific tag?

Tags: json, wordpress

I want to grab all the posts from http://example.com/tag/women in JSON format, and then repopulate some HTML using the content from that JSON link.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Seemed like this popular plugin has not been updated for two years: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-feed/

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ I believe it is going to be part of the wordpress core in the next release